# How to install a private managed Kubernetes on-premise?

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, orchestration, organization

Where do you start in case you need something like a managed Kubernetes solution to setup a multi-tenant orchestration solution on-premises?

- Any entity with its own container infrastructure has an access to the centrally managed orchestration service
- Entities **do not see** each other's containers

Note: if "managed Kubernetes" is kind of reserved term by AWS, maybe it's better to say "orchestration as a service"?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `OpenShift` container platform (https://www.openshift.com/products/container-platform/). They seem to provide on-premise options. You might want to start with `OpenShift Origin` - the community edition (https://github.com/openshift/origin) to test for free if it fits your plan.

Comment: OpenShift Origin has been rebranded OKD ”Origin Kubernetes Distribution”

Answer (score 1):

I don't think "Managed Kubernetes" is reserved for [AWS (EKS)](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/), there is [Microsoft's Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/kubernetes-service/) and [Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE)](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/) also, besides [Red Hat's OpenShift](http://www.openshift.com). Those work as SaaS (or KaaS if you will).

OpenShift has an on-premise version you can try called [MiniShift in the OpenShift.org](http://www.openshift.org) site, while there are other alternatives as Apache Mesos based [Mesosphere DC/OS](https://dcos.io/install/) or [Rancher with RancherOS containers](https://rancher.com/)

Comment: Minishift is like Minikube it is only for development work. The full distribution is called OKD (Origin Kuberentes Distribution) it used to be called Origin the renaming is to highlight its Kubernetes with some extras. The commercially supported version is Red Hat Container Platform.